# Trying to make my button, that is connected to an AJAX script work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

Hello I have two files that are supposed to be connected to one another. I want to send an AJAX request to another page that uses a sql query to send form information.

The application that I'm trying to create is a questionnaire with eight different questions, each questions has four answers and each answer has a value from the database. After you answer all eight questions you will see a button that submits an AJAX request to the page test.php, (named submitAJAX).

The problem is that the request isn't going through, the values from the form are not being sent to my database.

**The form page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

$qid = 1;
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $qid = intval($_POST['qid'])+1;

}


?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value="<?=$qid?>">
<?php
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where answer != '' && qid =".intval($qid));
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
?>
<input type='radio' name='answer1' class="radiobtn" value="<?php echo $row1['Point'];?>">
<input type='hidden' name='tid' class="tid" value="<?php echo $row1['tid'];?>">
<?php echo $row1['answer'];?><br>
<?php
}
?>
<?php if ($qid <= 8) {  ?>
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Tillbaka</button>
<button type="submit">Nästa</button>
<?php } else { ?>
<button id="submitAjax" type="submit">Avsluta provet</button>
     <?php } ?>  
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#submitAjax").click(function(){
        if($('.radiobtn').is(':checked')) { 
            var radiobtn = $('.radiobtn:checked').val();
            var qid = $('#qid').val();            
             var answer = $('input[name=answer1]:radio').val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: 'test.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: "radiobtn="+radiobtn+"&qid="+qid,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.status == true){
                        alert('points added');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('points not added');   
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
  </script>

    </body>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');
if(count($_GET) > 0){
   $answerPoint = intval($_GET['radiobtn']);
   $qid = intval($_GET['qid']);
$tid = intval($_GET['tid']);
   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO result (qid, points, tid) VALUES ($qid, $answerPoint, $tid)";
   $connect->query($sql2); 
   $lastid = $connect->insert_id;
   if($lastid>0) {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
}
   else{
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>0));
} 
}
?>
```

I've checked in the console log, as well as my network settings in inspect element, but I get no errors. 
Currently when I check up on test.php file, I get this message `{"status":0}` 
If I get `{"status":1}` then the request would be sent to the php file and values would be sent to my database.

Is there anything wrong with my code that I need to fix in order to send the form values to my database?

Comment: will you get `$lastid` anytime less than `0`?

Comment: does your success block alerts something?

Comment: @AnkiiG $lastid should always be more than 0

Comment: @JohnPangilinan I believe it should not, but I'm not getting any alerts when I press the submit ajax button. EDIT: my success is blocking alerts

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about what I'm supposed to do from here?